# C++ destruction order: Calling a field destructor before the class destructor

Tags: c++, destructor, object-destruction

Is there any way to call a field destructor before the class destructor?

Suppose I have 2 classes `Small` and `Big`, and `Big` contains an instance of `Small` as its field as such:

```
class Small
{
public:
    ~Small() {std::cout << "Small destructor" << std::endl;}
};

class Big
{
public:
    ~Big() {std::cout << "Big destructor" << std::endl;}

private:
    Small small;
};

int main()
{
    Big big;
}
```

This, of course, calls the big destructor before the small destructor:

```
Big destructor
Small destructor
```

I need the `Small` destructor to be called before the `Big` destructor since it does some cleanup necessary for the `Big` destructor.

I could:

1. call the `small.~Small()` destructor explicitly. -> This, however, calls the `Small` destructor twice: once explicitly, and once after the `Big` destructor has been executed.
2. have a `Small*` as the field and call `delete small;` in the `Big` destructor

I am aware that I can have a function in the `Small` class that does the cleanup and call it in the `Big` destructor, but I was wondering if there was a way to inverse the destructor order.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: I don't think there's a better way as the `Small` destructor will only be called when `Big` is getting destroyed, thus, after the `Big` destructor.

Comment: What kind of clean-up require for small's destructor to be called before big's destructor ?

Comment: "I need the small destructor to be called before the big destructor since it does some cleanup necessary for the big destructor." Your design is broken. Ask how to fix it, don't ask how to live with a broken design.

Comment: "I need the small destructor to be called before the big destructor" - this sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) - why do you need to do this?

Comment: Is there any better way to do what? Objects are destroyed in the reverse order as they are created. Anything else is just wrong in most cases

Comment: @n.m Yeah, that's broken, but sometimes require.Whole frameworks have such broken design e.g. QtQuick 5.3 hyrbrid app (C++ and jscript) would require something like that on linux, or app leaves hanging process behind itself.

Comment: I would suggest reworking the design instead of trying to circumvent the standard order of construction/destruction.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, that entered my mind. I guess I don't "need" to do it, I was just unsure if it "could" be done.

Comment: @nefas It's for destroying the zmq context, and the small destructor closes some sockets. The big destructor destroys the zmq context and needs all the sockets to be closed before it can be destroyed.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Thank you for that. Reversing the destruction order exactly seems to be Y. I'll see if I can redesign my code. That would be another question, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> call the small.~Small() destructor explicitly. -> This, however, calls the small destructor twice: once explicitly, and once after the big destructor has been executed.

Well, I don't know why you want to keep on with this flawing design, but you can solve the *problem* described in your first bullet using placement new.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Small {
    ~Small() {std::cout << "Small destructor" << std::endl;}
};

struct Big {
    Big() { ::new (storage) Small; }

    ~Big() {
        reinterpret_cast<Small *>(storage)->~Small();
        std::cout << "Big destructor" << std::endl;
    }

    Small & small() {
        return *reinterpret_cast<Small *>(storage);
    }

private:
    unsigned char storage[sizeof(Small)];
};

int main() {
    Big big;
}
```

You don't have anymore a variable of type `Small`, but with something like the `small` member function in the example you can easily work around it.

The idea is that you reserve enough space to construct in-place a `Small` and then you can invoke its destructor explicitly as you did. It won't be called twice, for all what the `Big` class has to release is an array of `unsigned char`s.
Moreover, you won't store your `Small` into the dynamic storage directly, for actually you are using a data member of your `Big` to create it in.

---

That being said, I'd suggest you to allocate it on the dynamic storage unless you have a good reason to do otherwise. Use a `std::unique_ptr` and reset it at the beginning of the destructor of `Big`. Your `Small` will go away before the body of the destructor is actually executed as expected and also in this case the destructor won't be called twice.

---

**EDIT**

As suggested in the comments, `std::optional` can be another viable solution instead of `std::unique_ptr`. Keep in mind that `std::optional` is part of the C++17, so if you can use it mostly depends on what's the revision of the standard to which you must adhere.

Comment: Yes, I agree with the dynamic storage. That's what I mentioned in '2'. I'm using this approach for now.

Comment: I wonder if a `std::optional` would be preferable to `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @ChrisDrew `Small` isn't optional as far as I understood. The semantics of an optional doesn't fit well here. My two cents.

Comment: Personally, I think the semantics of `std::optional` fits as well as a nullable smart pointer and has the benefit of not using dynamic memory.

Comment: In general, `storage` might not be correctly aligned for `Small`. You should use `std::aligned_storage`

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing *why* you want to do this, my only suggestion is to break up `Big` into the parts that need to be destroyed after `Small` from the rest and then use composition to include that inside `Big`. Then you have control over the order of destruction:

```
class Small
{
public:
    ~Small() {std::cout << "Small destructor" << std::endl;}
};

class BigImpl
{
public:
     ~BigImpl() { std::cout << "Big destructor" << std::endl; }
};

class Big
{
private:
    BigImpl bigimpl;
    Small small;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of destructor calls cannot be changed. The proper way to design this is that `Small` performs its own cleanup.

If you cannot change `Small` then you could make a class `SmallWrapper` that contains a `Small` and also can perform the required cleanup.

The standard containers `std::optional` or `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` might suffice for this purpose.